# Stay in same location on submit the form

Tags: xhtml

When i submitting the form the page will navigate to starting of page.

i want to stay on same location. is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, instead of using the form submission, send an asynchronous request in JavaScript using XHR. To give a concrete example, suppose you have a simple form that looks like:

```
<form method="POST" action="/path/to/submit">
  <input id="input_name" name="input_name" type="text" value="value" />
</form>
```

Using XHR, it might look something like the following (using the [Closure library](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/docs/index.html) for XHR):

```
<script>
  goog.require('goog.net.XhrIo');
  var submitCompleted = function() {
     alert('Submitted!');
  };

  var submitAction = function() {
     var value = document.getElementById('input_name').value;
     goog.net.XhrIo.send(
       '/path/to/submit',
        submitCompleted,
       'POST',
       'input_name=' + encodeURIComponent(value));
  };
</script>
```

I'm assuming that you still keep the same input element as before, but that you define your `onsubmit` function to invoke `submitAction` instead of using the default submission behavior of your form.

Comment: May i know how will i do that please...i never tried that method.